# Change url (path) of uploaded image Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I upload image I get this destination:

`C:\xampp\htdocs\AUCTION\laravel\public\images/85.jpg`

I need to get this: `/images/85.jpg`

How can I do this ?

This is my code for upload:

```
 $request->file('img_1')->move(public_path('images'), $request->file('img_1')->getClientOriginalName());
   $product->img_1 = public_path('images') . '/' . $request->file('img_1')->getClientOriginalName();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$imgName = $request->file('img_1')->getClientOriginalName();
$request->file('img_1')->move(public_path('images'), $imgName);
$product->img_1 = 'images/'.$imgName;
```

Comment: Glad I could help here )